# deregister watchers in ng-bind when item is not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS with `ng-repeat`. Each item in the repeater is huge item that contains many `ng-bind`s and the list wrapped with a scrollbar. I would like to write a code that deregister the watches of each `ng-bind` when the item is not visible (out of the scroll) and register the watch again when the item is visible.
I have two questions:
1. Does such code already exist somewhere?
2. ng-bind create a watch. How can I gain access to the watch deregistration (`$scope.$watch` returns the deregistration method but this happened inside the ng-bind directive)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you have a viewport and you want only currently viewport elements to be watched ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [angular-viewport-watch](https://github.com/shahata/angular-viewport-watch), with nested tables (with many rows) which are scrolled in a scrollable container.

Had to fix some issues ([this](https://github.com/shahata/angular-viewport-watch/issues/9#issuecomment-231485765) and [this](https://github.com/shahata/angular-viewport-watch/issues/10#issuecomment-234937001)) but overall it works well. When an element is out of the viewport all its watches are removed (recursively), and when it re-appears on the viewport the watchers are added back.

I'm using [*annotate-watchers*](http://jasonstitt.com/angular-js-count-watchers) snippet (on chrome) to easily see how many watchers are related to each DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have access to the ng-bind on an element, you can create a simple directive that passes in the scope. When you have a scope you can access the watches with `$$watchers`. I made a fiddle to show that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2sRF7/2/).

```
link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
    console.log(scope.$$watchers);
}
```

As far as your scrolling issue, you have a couple options. I haven't used this before, but there appears to be a [plugin](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview), for which I won't vouch for the correctness. The theory behind an inview directive is that you attach a scroll listener to your container. After scrolls, you calculate which elements are in view.

After this you can trigger an inview function for those that are inview and trigger outview (which could remove watchers) for the others that used to be in view.

Let me know if you have questions. Hope this helps!

Comment: $$watchers doesn't allow me to deregister watchers. I don't want to use in-view instead of ng-bind.

Comment: You can just splice a watch away from $$watchers, effectively unwatching it. Keep the spliced $watch around and add it back in when the in-view is triggered. You need to use ng-bind AND in-view.

Comment: If you'll look carefully on AngularJS deregistration function, it does: arrayRemove(array, watcher); lastDirtyWatch = null;
arrayRemove() is removing the watcher from $$watchers, but what does lastDirtyWatch = null; do?

Comment: It's used in the digest cycle. You can check out that code here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4a6a3ba7fb08ce99007893ef75365a3e8aff938a/src/ng/rootScope.js#L591 It is an optimization for dirty checking.